# Gauss curvature and second fundamental form after a rigid motion

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a regular surface.
Let $\phi$: $\mathbb{R}^3\to \Bbb R^3$ be a rigid motion,  $\phi(p) = Ap+b$.
Denoted with $N$ the Gauss application of the surface $S$,

1. show that $N' = A\circ N\circ \phi^{-1}$ is the Gauss application for $S'=\phi(S)$.
2. show that ${dN'}_{\phi(p)}= A\circ {dN}_p\circ A^{-1}$.
3. show that $I\!I_{\phi(p)}(d\phi_p(v)) = I\!I'_{\phi(p)}(Av) = I\!I_p(v)$, for $v\in T_pS$.

I understood the concept but I can't manage to prove the analytic results..

Comment: $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism from $S$ to $\phi(S)$. 2) comes from differentiating 1). 3) is false as stated (the domains don't match). Do you have any intuition on 1)?

Comment: I can't get to any.. by the way why is 3) false? My intuition on it is that the second fundamental form would be the same (in a point) for a surface after a rigid motion